# Shortest way to find if a pattern is in any of two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a pattern that I need to know (by returning a `boolean`) if is contained in any of two strings, and I want to know how to do this in the shortest way possible.

I know I can use `any()` for larger amounts of strings but I was looking for the shortest way to accomplish this for string *pairs*, because using `any()` would require list comprehension at the very least.

I was expecting something like this, but it does not work:

```
pattern in (string1 or string2)
```

I was getting confused because this code actually works for `string1`, but it only checks `string2` if `string1` is `False` or `None` (I think).

Ultimately I can use `any((pattern in s for s in (string1, string2)))`, but it's less **pretty** or **readable** inside the code.

Comment: `pattern in string1+string2` concatinate the strings

Comment: @VaibhavVishal that can create an issue if the end of `string1` plus the start of `string2` match the pattern. It does not happen in my case (I don't think), but it can.

Comment: if you want to know if the pattern is in *any* of the strings, whats wrong with only checking the second string if it is not in the first string?

Comment: @Flob I mean't that it only checks the second string if the first string **is** `False` or `None`

Comment: you just have to remove the brackets, and it works

Comment: @Flob: no it will not. The part after the `or` will *always* return `True`, even if the substring is not in `string2`.

Comment: right, i forgot that the OP wants a boolean variable and instead thought of a conditional clause. In that case, @iBugs answer is correct

Comment: You only need one pair of brackets inside the *any* expression - I don't believe there is anything simpler than that, if you're planning to generalize to more than two strings: *any(pattern in s for s in (string1, string2))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no nitpicks. Just do the most intuitive:

```
has_pattern = pattern in string1 or pattern in string2
```

Note that `(string1 or string2)` is almost always wrong by your intention, as the result of that expression is `string1` if it's non-empty, and `string2` otherwise.

Comment: As Vaibhav already said, concatenation can be useful, and as I already replied, there can be the issue where `string1` + `string2` create a match that was otherwise inexistent, although this can be circumvented by joining them via some symbol/combination of symbols that you're sure is not in your pattern. In my case, I ended up using `string1'||'string2`. (Add something like this to the question and I'll delete the comment)